# Xamarin.Android RecyclerView fed with Database

Tags: android, image, api, xamarin, android-recyclerview

How can I fill a RecyclerView in Xamarin Android with a SQL Server database that has images and information about the images?
Or if not a SQL Server database but with an API.
Could you please share some tutorial doing this? I can't find anything that is not local (using drawable folder images).

I'm looking a result like this (image):
[image: Example]

So, once again, the problem with this result is that is made with a local-drawable folder-images list, and I need to feed the RecyclerView with an **API** that has the exact same information and images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: First you should create WEB API Interface in SQL server into Mobile Application.

Step 2: After that WEP API creation you need to config in Xamarin Android Project.

Here given below link, i have explained step by step implementation Recyclerview

https://xmonkeys360.com/2018/01/24/create-android-recyclerview-using-material-design/